# Is it possible to enhance the query defined in a Spring Data @Query annotation?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm looking to customize `@Query` with filters. A simple example (not real world):

```
@Query("select c from Customer where id = ?1") 
Optional<Customer> findCustomerById(String id, @Nullable Context context)
```

This is a multi-tenant environment. Depending on various factors (the entity itself, information in the context object) additional filtering may or may not be applied. The end result would be a query like this:

`select c from Customer where id = 'id' and tenantId = '1' and ...`

This is an existing solution with hundreds of entities and many repositories. Modifying existing repositories is not an option, so filtering mechanisms like `Specification` are out. This should be transparent to the user, even if this is achieved with a new custom annotation (i.e. `@CustomQuery`).

Note that I already have a solution for named method generated queries, so `findById(String id, Context context)` works. More complex queries are currently managed with criteria builders and various helper classes to apply appropriate filtering, but being able to use `@Query` would at least be a nice option to have.

So is this something that is possible?